# User is getting session from other logged in user with Rails / Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise with Ruby on Rails to develop a game.

Users are able to login and join the game.

When they first login, everything is fine - it shows that they are logged in as the expected person.

But very rarely I have noticed (both in real world use as well as once in testing) a situation that boggles me.

Suddenly one of the users "becomes" a different user.  As if they had logged in as the other user.  They have full access to their account, and Rails thinks that they have logged in as the different user.  Everything such as "current_user.name" and "current_user.email" are all according to the other user, the one that they were not previously logged in as, and a user they have no permission to become.

I can't figure out where in my code this might be coming from.  I don't want to post the entirety of my code here, so I was hoping for some brainstorming of *how* it would even be possible to cause something like this to happen in my code - or am I more likely looking at a devise bug where devise is screwing up the session it returns under certain race conditions?

The latter is somewhat scarier to deal with from a general security perspective for any site that uses devise, but I figure someone else would have seen this by now.  So I figure it must be in my code - but nowhere in my code do I touch the session info, nor do I ever do anything weird like assign the current_user to anything.

To be very clear about what happens:

1. "Bob" logs in on his device as "Bob" and sees that he is "Bob" (current_user.name) and has access to "Bob" things.
2. "Joe" logs in on his device as "Joe" and sees that he is "Joe" (current_user.name) and has access to "Joe" things.
3. After following one of any number of internal links (that don't alter/set user info), the device that "Joe" is using is now showing up as "Bob" (current_user.name) and has access to "Bob" things (like editing his profile page, etc.. - all guarded by current_user).

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

My devise setup allows for email/password login as well as oauth login with Facebook and the like.

--

As requested, here is the devise migration:

--

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: I experienced a similar problem years ago and we were able to find the root cause in a misconfigured database configuration. Multiple forked processes were using the same database connection and in very rare cases when loading a session one process got the session that was requested by another process. What session store do you use in your application?

Comment: What exactly does "real world" mean? If it means that you yourself are testing your application on the same machine with the same browser (and e.g. multiple tabs), the "error" very likely stems from there. You can log in to the same app multiple times using a private tab/private window of your browser, or by using multiple different browsers (e.g. firefox and chromium).

Comment: Just putting in my 2 cents here: Devise allows you to have multiple models signed in at the same time if you configure it to do so. Maybe you can check that? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-multiple-models

Comment: @Felix - "real world" means multiple people using separate devices.  I had two people logged in on different devices and when they joined a game, one of them was now logged in as someone else - someone else who had been "oauth'd" by Facebook, so it was quite a surprise.

Comment: @spickermann - I haven't specified a session store, so I presume it's just using the browser cookies - and somehow it sends the wrong cookie to one of the browsers at some point, weirdly enough this is *not* happening at login.  Or else wherever the translation of session -> identity is being corrupted.

Comment: Could you please share your Devise Migration here...

Comment: @SantoshAryal Devise migration added

Comment: I had a similar problem. The reason was that my UI was cached on the browser so even if the User X logged out and another User Y logged in, the UI of the previous User X would show to User Y.

Comment: Jun - interesting possibility, although in this case it was two unique users on their own browsers that had not been shared and had not been used to login to any other users on this system.

Comment: Have you found a root cause by any chance? We are experiencing similar problems. I thought initially that it might be a thread safety issue but after going single thread multiple workers puma setup I can still rarely see that behavior. My setup is more complicated (eg includes JWT tokens) but surprisingly the issue related to sessions swap looks similar.

Comment: I have not found a solution.  I think the only way to debug it would be to figure out a way to setup a "multi-user" testbench that can reliable see the switch happen, then start removing components.  I actually think it's something inside of devise even though it's "battle tested" - my bet is that it's a specific configuration that isn't getting good testing and is causing the problem.  I can't even figure out how I could create a bug in my current code that would cause this kind of id switching.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways this can happen, obviously it's hard to tell from here what is going wrong. Since Devise is battle tested, I'd assume it's something you do, rather than device is doing (of course it is still possible that Devise has a bug, but more likely your code is buggy)

Do you have

- Static variables that hold information related to the user
- Usernames that are not unique (enforced on the DB level)
- Users with same email address created through different sign up mechanisms
- Changed anything in the session handling?
  ?

Can you find a way to reproduce the error locally? Perhaps with a script that logs in as different users and checks that the user stays the same.
What Server does it happen with?
What Session Store do you use?

Comment: I don't have any static vars for the user - I use "current_user" to get and show the name info.  This isn't about a username uniqueness problem, someone actually went from being one user to another ("Bob" suddenly becomes "Gerry" and has access to everything "Gerry" has).   It's not email addresses either.  Most users are using oauth, and we only have about 100 users at this point.  I haven't edited the session handling.

Comment: Mihgt tbe tricky to debug without seeing the code, without being able to reproduce.

Comment: I agree - that's why I was hoping for some devise experts who could tell me what kind of pathways could cause something like this.  I don't even fully know how devise stores the session, and/or when it sends new session info, or perhaps if there's some way to turn on devise logging.

Comment: Devise uses the provided session. If you have not changed anything, then it will be cookie store.
Key to fix it will be to reproduce it. Especially if you want to be sure that a potential fix actually fixes it.
Write a script that hammers your server (locally could be enough, since it happened there as well) or so?

Comment: Once I've reproduced it, and see that the cookie has been changed, how do I find the source?

Comment: Sorry, can't help without seeing code. I understand that ths might be difficult. Perhaps you can find a way to reproduce and then strip down the app until you can share?

Comment: I'll see how much the problem haunts me - that would be a massive undertaking.

Comment: This would scare me. If it happened once, it can happen again. And users seeing other users info is a huge security/privacy risk.
First step is to be able to reproduce the problem. This you could do without sharing code. Just write a script that logs in and then requests profile info over and over again. Start it for multiple users and see if it leaks other session info.

Comment: And it scares me.  I'll look into automating some logins to devise, though I confess this is new territory for me, since this is my first devise project.

Comment: As said, not sure this is related to devise. Honestly I don't use it that often but there are lots of people who do. 
If you can share some code I can look over it.